# Convert URL from JSON into image for UIImageView using objectForKey

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, asynchronous, uiimageview

I've got an image's URL successfully being received, but I have no clue to convert that URL into an actual image to be used inside of an ImageView. Many have suggested asynchronously loading the image first. Unfortunately, that's all they have to say, and leave me without further explanation. My JSON is setup in a hierarchy, so I'm using keys for the values. Should I be sending the image URL in the same JSON file as the strings? Is JSON the correct way to do this in general? Any help is appreciated.

```
    NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://domain.com/json2.php"];
    NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
    NSError *error;

    jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    [tableView reloadData]; // if tableView is unidentified make the tableView IBOutlet
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return jsonArray.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NeedCardTableViewCell *cell = (NeedCardTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"needCard" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *needs = jsonArray[indexPath.row]; // get the data dict for the row
    cell.textNeedTitle.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needTitle"];
    cell.textNeedPoster.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needPoster"];
    cell.textNeedDescrip.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needDescrip"];

    return cell;
```

I'd need my image to load in the UIImageView titled "imageProfPic".

```
@interface NeedCardTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textNeedTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textNeedPoster;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textNeedDescrip;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageProfPic;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a third party library like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). In the readme you'll find a sample that fits your needs, just use the URL stored from the JSON parsing.
If you want to do it by yourself you can use [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html):

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("imageQueue", NULL), ^{ 
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:needs[@"yourURLKey"]]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [cell.imageProfPic setImage:image];
    });
});
```

This downloads the image in a background thread, and sets it in the main thread (UI thread)

Comment: Shouldn't you convert dispatch_sync to dispatch_async so that any other operations won't hold up this dispatch and lock up the main thread? Also, this is the most efficient way to do it, @dvdowns

Comment: Well not using SDWebImage, but definitively the grand central dispatch

Comment: Yep, sorry, typo, I meant async.

Comment: @A'saDickens feel free to chime in as well, thanks for the constructive help btw

Comment: @andreamazz I'm now realizing that your snippet is for the Grand Central Dispatch method, and not using the SDWebImage library. I've placed your snipped below the objectForKey calls and above the return cell in side of the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. I'm now getting the error _NSCFString isFileURL error. Thoughts?

Comment: This is the code I ended up going with, and it worked like a charm!: 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:needs[@"userImage"]];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [cell.imageProfPic setImage:image];
        });
    });

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a framework like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) which comes with a category to directly load images from a URL.

```
    [cell.imageProfPic setImageWithURL:url];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourImageURLString]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```